# Deserialize string into object array

Tags: c#, sql, json, serialization

I'm new to JSON Serialization and Deserialization, so I've been googling alot about this topic, but I couldn't come to figuring out my problem. My main goal is to deserialize the JSON string and write a SQL insert statement from it. Being new to this topic, I'm not sure what deserializing a JSON string returns, but I read somewhere that it returns an object array? For example how would I deserialize this JSON string:

```
[{"First_Name":"Bob","Last_Name":"Smith","Job":"Engineer"},
{"First_Name":"Jane","Last_Name":"Doe","Job":"Scientist"}]
```

and deserialize it into a SQL statement?

Comment: It depends... which JSON library are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: I'm using JavaScriptSerializer in the .NET FCL.

Comment: `and deserialize it into a SQL statement?` What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

Using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
```

Using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var users = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<User>>(json);
```

---

```
public class User
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```